# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSettings", referenced from

Tags: ios, objective-c

> Get error for arm64 while add facebook sdk and and my xcode build faild due to these error/ please look at this once.
>
> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/chetumac-007/Desktop/Backup/backup on 25th oct/MamaBear-iOS-App/MobileAppTracker.framework/MobileAppTracker, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x56 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x73 0x2F 0x43 0x75 0x72 0x72 0x65 0x6E 0x74 ) which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /Users/chetumac-007/Desktop/Backup/backup on 25th oct/MamaBear-iOS-App/MobileAppTracker.framework/MobileAppTracker
>   Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSettings", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
>         objc-class-ref in SocialSettingsViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

this is my valid architechture directory.

> i386
>   armv7s
>   $(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT)

Comment: I think it's telling you that the version of MobileAppTracker.framework that you're trying to link to is not built for arm64.

Comment: @PhillipMills yes, its gives me warning for that, should i remove arm64 from my build arc?